# Count consecutive spaces(&nbsp) at the start of the string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of strings where I would like to see the number of consecutive spaces(&nbsp) at the start of the string in Python.

Consider the the three below strings like,

```
1.Test1 False (String 1)
2.    Test2 False (String 2)
3.        Test3 False (String 3)
```

I need the Output to be like (count of leading zeros of each string)

```
0
4
8
```

corresponding to the number of white spaces at the start of each of the strings.

Comment: Please post the source code you've tried so far.

Comment: One possibility is using a [regexp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: so far i haven't tried any.

Comment: You may get more help if you attempt some code yourself and post it with your question, you could try something that involves `str.count(' ')`.

Comment: There's many ways to do that.

If it's an assignemnt, then assume, that you learnt already all you need to solve the problem and use only what you learnt.
What commands / expressions, language constructs, operators you know already?

This will help to guide you to an answer, that you were supposed to find.

Did you  learn  how to: 
determine the length of a string strip off white space of a string? regular expressions, iterate through the characters of a string? increment a counter? use enumerate(), about for loops, about while loops.

How would you do required task as a human?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most pythonic way to do this is the following:

```
def count_start_spaces(s):
    return len(s) - len(s.lstrip())
```

Given the following input:

```
strings = ["Test1 False (String 1)","    Test2 False (String 2)","        Test3 False (String 3)"]
list(map(count_start_space, strings))
# output: [0, 4, 8]
```

Comment: the solution I'd use as well if this were a real problem.

Wouldn't use it though if it were an assignment and I were supposed to code a solution. All depends on whether it as a coding problem or an exercise, that was supposed to apply what has been learnt so far.

Comment: thank u gelonida. This solution should work